# react js : TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.state.hiring.map(h => (
  <FormApp
    condType={h.type}
    condRef={h.ref}
    label={h.name}
    labelName={h.name}
    name={h.id}
    id={h.name}
    validations={h.required == true ? [this.required] : null}
    dataList={this.state[h.ref]}
    onChange={this.onChangeInput}
  />
));
```

I want to 
`if (h.requered == true) { return [this.required] } else { null }`

I have problem

react js : **TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))**

Comment: It looks like `validations` expects to be passed an array, not `null`. So maybe pass an empty array instead of `null`?

Comment: This.state.hiring is null, you can set the initial state of hiring to an empty array instead.

Comment: What is `this.state.hiring`? Could you update the code? I bet you're getting error from this line, not `validations`, because it's the only iterating part in your snippet

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can modify your code like this:

```
const { hiring } = this.state;
hiring instanceof Array && hiring.map(h => { // ==> Validate hiring before use it.
        if (h.requered == true) {
            return (
                <FormApp
                    condType={h.type}
                    condRef={h.ref}
                    label={h.name}
                    labelName={h.name}
                    name={h.id}
                    id={h.name}
                    validations={h.required == true ? [this.required] : null}
                    dataList={this.state[h.ref]}
                    onChange={this.onChangeInput}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
```